# In Hololens, how can I construct a SoftwareBitmap from image captured from webcam?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, bitmap, hololens

The offending line of code is

```
var decoder = await BitmapDecoder.CreateAsync(stream);
```

I construct the stream object both as:

```
using (var stream = new InMemoryRandomAccessStream())
{
      using (var dw = new DataWriter(stream))
      {
           dw.WriteBytes(byteBuffer);
           await dw.StoreAsync();
      }
      // ...
}
```

and as:

```
using (var stream = new MemoryStream(byteBuffer))
```

but Hololens seems to not be able to construct stream at all in runtime.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You want to display the image on the screen?

Comment: No, I want to detect Faces with FaceDetector.

Comment: Sorry. I have not used that API before. I suggest you look at the sample projects for face detector [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/HolographicFaceTracking)

Comment: Oops. Wrong link. Check [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/BasicFaceDetection/cs)